# Can we remove-improve the human verification script?

Tags: bug, user-interface, captcha

This happens to me many times and I think it's boring. The human verification page prevent me to post an answer and it takes a long time for that the captcha box appears  *(perhaps it was because of the slow connection? I don't know)* and this takes a long time to the point that I think my answer may become useless. I wonder if this check is essential and if it happens that a script can cause problems for this site so to think making this precaution *(script)*. If this is the case I suggest just that verification would be  smarter and it *senses* that I just  posted  an answer to help people and not something else.

Comment: I don't think I've ever encountered a captcha... (Or it was a very long time ago.) Does anyone know what the rules are? Apparently they are reduced for 10k users?

Comment: No there is a captcha and we should select two pictures of ice cream, this is what happen to me.

Comment: Do you compose the answer on the site or do you paste it from somewhere else? Also, are you logged in before you answer?

Comment: Yes I logged in the site and I composed the answer directly on it.@quid

Comment: How often is this happening to you (what frequency? once every how many posts?). Also - are you in a place where the internet connection is shared by others using the site?

Comment: @Oded I have the same problem, mainly it looks to happen when I paste an answer that I drafted off-line, as it should be when it is more than a comment. Now, the annoying fact is that my connection is quite slow (.."digital divide " they call it !), and (just few minutes ago) it was also asking that my browser should be UPDATED! If a CAPTCHA has to be, please change to a less demanding one: *digitally-divided* people would be grateful not to be also *math-divided*